# How can I download Minecraft from Aptoide?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I am trying to download Aptoide through Safari to get the latest version of Minecraft, but it keeps sending a message that Safari cannot download this file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

From [Aptoide](http://aptoide.com) (emphasis mine):

> Aptoide is the largest independent **Android app store** and allows one to setup and manage your own Android Store.

You cannot *directly* run Android software on an Apple product.

Look for [Minecraft on the iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/minecraft-pocket-edition/id479516143?mt=8) store or download it directly from [the official site](https://minecraft.net/download) for OS X.